# ¿Cómo puedo generar estilo a este código?

Tags: php, html, css

quiero que el codigo tenga CSS, pero es un archivo totalmente PHP, o sea, extensión PHP. ¿Cómo hago para que tenga estilo?, lo que deseo es cuando se genere la búsqueda, el resultado tenga formateado la tabla y este con color, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<?php
// Conexión a la base de datos
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "esquema";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Conexión fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Procesamiento de la búsqueda
if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
    $nombre_buscar = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nombre_buscar']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla_clientes WHERE Nombres LIKE '%$nombre_buscar%'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
        // Mostrar resultados en una tabla
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Nombres</th><th>Género</th><th>Profesión</th><th>País</th><th>Fecha</th></tr>";
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $fila["id"] . "</td><td>" . $fila["Nombres"] . "</td><td>" . $fila["Genero"] . "</td><td>" . $fila["Profesion"] . "</td><td>" . $fila["Pais"] . "</td><td>" . $fila["fecha"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "No se encontraron resultados";
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Pues agrega el atributo `style=""` y el estilo que quieras, dentro de las etiquetas...

Comment: Siempre será mostrado en una pagina con HTML. Así que el comentario anterior te da la respuesta.